# PHP-MONGO How to update a particular field

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to develop a RESTful PHP API based on MongoDB. I make a POST passing a JSON body like this:

```
{"id":"1","timestamp":"blah blah","value:"blah"}
```

Then in the collection called "device" I want to create a structure like this:

```
{ _id: 1
alt: blah
lng : blah
senseddata: {
    timestamp: blah
    value :blah
    }
    {
    timestamp: blah blah
    value: blah
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

In other words, I just only want to update "senseddata" field. So I wrote this query in Mongo Shell:

```
db.device.update({"_id":1},{$push:{"senseddata":{"timestamp":1234,"value":"12"}}})
```

and it works perfectly. Now I tried to do the same in PHP. I wrote this:

```
$id = $data['id'];
$timestamp = $data['timestamp'];
$value = $data['value'];
$collection = $db->device;
$collection->update(array("_id" => $id),
                         array('$push' => array('senseddata' => array('timespamp' => $timestamp,'value' => $value)))
                   );
```

and it didn't work. Then I tried using '$set' and I noticed a strange behaviour: if I leave my code as it is, it doesn't work. But if I write like that:

```
//$id = $data['id'];
$timestamp = $data['timestamp'];
$value = $data['value'];
$id = 1;
$collection = $db->device;
$collection->update(array("_id" => $id),
                         array('$push' => array('senseddata' => array('timespamp' => $timestamp,'value' => $value)))
                   );
```

it works (i didn't understand why) but it changes (as expected) entirely the structure of my collection. And it's not what I want. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two pieces of code are exactly the same except that you have hard coded the `$data['id']` value in the second as such I do not think this is a problem with MongoDB but instead a problem with the data your passing.

I would debug your application further.

#### Edit

Your JSON shows the `id` as string:

```
{"id":"1","timestamp":"blah blah","value:"blah"}
```

But you never convert to `int`. MongoDB is type aware so you need:

```
$id = intval($data['id']);
$timestamp = $data['timestamp'];
$value = $data['value'];
$collection = $db->device;
$collection->update(
    array("_id" => $id),
    array('$push' => array('senseddata' => array('timespamp' => $timestamp,'value' => $value)))
);
```

Comment: Ah, nice catch. I was looking at the query. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah I see the problem now, his JSON has the id as string and he never converts to int :P

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a newbie but this solving makes me understand a lot of things. Thanks again :)

Comment: @EmilianoAlbanese glad to have helped :)